# Scalaz Tree - finding the min/max depth from a TreeLoc set

Tags: scala, tree, stream, scalaz

In Scalaz I have a `Tree[A]` like;

```
'A'.node('B'.leaf, 'C'.node('D'.leaf), 'E'.leaf)
```

Now lets say I have a function which recurses through the tree and returns a `TreeLoc`;

```
def getCharLoc(c: Char) = tree.loc.find(_.getLabel == c)
```

Then I do something like

```
Seq('D','E').flatMap(getCharLoc)
```

How could I find the lowest and/or the highest `loc` in tree. In the above example `'D'` is the lowest/deepest location and `'E'` is the highest/shallowest location.

I was thinking each `loc` has a `.path` method which returns a `Stream` from the loc to the root. Calling `.length` on this would give a count of the depth which could be compared in a fold left but it feels clunky.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why exactly is 'E' the 'shallowest' location, and not 'B' for example?

Comment: It's the shallowest out of the input set which was just e & d. If talking about the entire tree then yes it's b.... Along with c and e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to count parents with a tail recursive function, not sure if you would consider that more or less "clunky":

```
val tree = 'A'.node('B'.leaf, 'C'.node('D'.leaf), 'E'.leaf)

@tailrec def countParents(loc: Option[TreeLoc[Char]], acc: Int = 0): Int = 
  loc >>= { _.parent } match {
    case None => acc
    case next @ _ => countParents(next, acc + 1)
  }

println(countParents(tree.loc.find(_.getLabel == 'D'))) // 2
println(countParents(tree.loc.find(_.getLabel == 'E'))) // 1
```